# @font-face doesnt work in chrome - crossbrowsing trouble

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

Recenty a client has uploaded his website and the font that was defined on font-face stopped working. In tests environment, it worked.

Curiously the font-face links are all correct. I adapted to the fontspring bulletproof syntax model and still didnt work.

I`m using font-face like this.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Panton Bold';
  src: url('http://cannes.com.br/panton/Panton-Bold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('http://cannes.com.br/panton/Panton-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('http://cannes.com.br/panton/Panton-Bold.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('http://cannes.com.br/panton/Panton-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('http://cannes.com.br/panton/Panton-Bold.svg') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
</style>
```

Would anyone have any guesses about this? Thanks

Comment: If the website is not hosted on `http://cannes.com.br/`, and that domain is not allowing cross-origin requests, it likely won't work. Look at the network requests being made and look for errors in your console.

Comment: Check your browser's Console Tab for errors. It should be a CORS problem.